# Poles defining a function - do two equivalent expressions share the same poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Take a term $f$, with poles at $z=1, z=2$, i.e

$f=\dfrac{g}{(z-1)(z-2)}$.

Now assume that $f$ can be split into two (or more) terms, as

$f \equiv h_1 + h_2$

Is it true that $h_1$ and $h_2$ **must** have the same poles as $f$? Is it true that if not, then their overall form must have the total same poles, i.e if they don't individally have the same poles as $f$, then the terms must have a form like

$h_1 = \dfrac{a}{(z-2)} \quad h_2 = \dfrac{b}{(z-1)}$

Comment: You can always replace $(h_1, h_2)$ by $(h_1 + \phi, h_2 - \phi)$ with an arbitrary function $\phi$ (having as much poles as you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a simplified version of the situation, suppose you have a single variable $\,z\,$ and define the simple poles $\,p_0 := 1/z,\, p_1 := 1/(z-1),\, p_2 := 1/(z-2),\,$ and so on. Suppose you have finite set of simple poles $\,P := \{p_i,p_j,\dots,p_k\}\,$ and a finite sum of them
$\,S := c_i\,p_i + c_j\,p_j + \cdots + c_k\,p_k.\,$ Then the poles are **linearly** independent and so any two sums $\,S\,$ and $\,S'\,$ are equal iff they have the same poles with the same coefficients. You can have higher order poles such as
 $\,p_i^2\,$ and $\, p_j^3\,$ and so on, but they are all linearly independent. Think of P as a set of independent variables used to construct multi-variable polynomials. Linear algebra rules here. Any **rational** function of 
$\,z\,$ with poles in $\,P\,$ can be uniquely split into the sum of a polynomial in the simple poles $\,P\,$ and a polynomial in $\,z.\,$

As a simple example:
$$ \frac{2 + z + 3 z^2 + 4 z^3 + 5 z^4}{z\, (z - 1)\, (z - 2)} =
 \frac1z + \frac{-15}{z-1} + \frac{64}{z-2}  + 19 + 5\,z.$$

P.S. Try this decomposition yourself. Here is some Wolfram Mathematica code:

```
decompRatFunc[r_, z_] := Module[ {poles, poly}, poles = 
  DeleteCases[r // Factor // Apart, _?NumberQ | z^n_. _. /; n > 0];
  poly = r - poles // Simplify // Expand; {poles, poly}];
```